# Unknown datatypes IRQn_Type,

Tags: c, makefile, stm32, hal, cmsis

When trying to build my project, I get errors like:

```
Drivers/CMSIS/Include/core_cm4.h:1816:41: error: unknown type name 'IRQn_Type'; did you mean 'ITM_Type'?
 1816 | __STATIC_INLINE void __NVIC_SetPriority(IRQn_Type IRQn, uint32_t priority)
      |                                         ^~~~~~~~~
```

or

```
Drivers/CMSIS/Include/core_cm4.h: In function 'NVIC_EncodePriority':
Drivers/CMSIS/Include/core_cm4.h:1869:64: error: '__NVIC_PRIO_BITS' undeclared (first use in this function)
 1869 |   PreemptPriorityBits = ((7UL - PriorityGroupTmp) > (uint32_t)(__NVIC_PRIO_BITS)) ? (uint32_t)(__NVIC_PRIO_BITS) : (uint32_t)(7UL - PriorityGroupTmp);
```

So it seems that IRQn_Type and __NVIC_PRIO_BITS are not defined.

As far as I understand, the datatypes are defined in the stm32f407xx.h file and I am telling make already where to find it:
-IDrivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include

---

#### Edit

I just saw the first errors are these:

```
In file included from Drivers/CMSIS/DSP/Include/arm_math.h:322,
                 from Src/dsp/dsp.c:1:
Drivers/CMSIS/Include/core_cm4.h:105:8: error: #error "Compiler generates FPU instructions for a device without an FPU (check __FPU_PRESENT)"
  105 |       #error "Compiler generates FPU instructions for a device without an FPU (check __FPU_PRESENT)"
      |        ^~~~~

In file included from Src/dsp/dsp.c:3:
Drivers/CMSIS/Include/core_cm4.h:1688:39: error: unknown type name 'IRQn_Type'; did you mean 'ITM_Type'?
 1688 | __STATIC_INLINE void __NVIC_EnableIRQ(IRQn_Type IRQn)
      |                                       ^~~~~~~~~
      |                                       ITM_Type
```

My template makefile was generated by CubeMX, but I made some changes (changed the structure of my folders, added defines and include directories).

```
# C defines
C_DEFS =  \
-DUSE_HAL_DRIVER \
-DSTM32F407xx \
-DARM_MATH_CM4 

# C includes
C_INCLUDES =  \
-IConfigs \
-ISrc \
-IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc \
-IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy \
-IDrivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include \
-IDrivers/CMSIS/Include \
-IDrivers/CMSIS/DSP/Include
```

---

I get just this error:

```
In file included from Drivers/CMSIS/DSP/Include/arm_math.h:322,
                 from Src/dsp/filter.h:9,
                 from Src/dsp/filter.c:1:
Drivers/CMSIS/Include/core_cm4.h:105:8: error: #error "Compiler generates FPU instructions for a device without an FPU (check __FPU_PRESENT)"
  105 |       #error "Compiler generates FPU instructions for a device without an FPU (check __FPU_PRESENT)"
      |        ^~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:228: build/filter.o] Error 1
```

if I put this lines above my `#include <arm_math.h>`.

```
#define STM32F407xx
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
```

---

After adding also `-D__FPU_PRESENT` to the defines, I still get the error:

```
In file included from Src/dsp/dsp.c:4:
Drivers/CMSIS/Include/core_cm4.h:1688:39: error: unknown type name 'IRQn_Type'; did you mean 'ITM_Type'?
 1688 | __STATIC_INLINE void __NVIC_EnableIRQ(IRQn_Type IRQn)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure that the header file for your particular microcontroller is included, you need to define the relevant macro. In your case, you need to ensure that `-DSTM32F407xx` is passed to your compiler. How exactly you do this will depend on your build environment.

Once you have done so, the relevant header file will be [automatically included via `stm32f4xx.h`](https://github.com/MaJerle/stm32fxxx_hal_libraries/blob/b295f87c649cccf0c27bcd6f8f3695666fdde571/00-HAL_DRIVERS/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include/stm32f4xx.h#L151).

In case you're wondering how to ensure that `stm32f4xx.h`, in turn, is included - and if it needs to be included explicitly in your own source files ...

Typically, you won't need to explicitly include `stm32f4xx.h`. As long as you include the header file for one of the standard peripherals - such as the RCC or GPIO - it will be automatically included.

So the include chain might look something like follows:

- `stm32f4xx_rcc.h` <- include in your source files

  - `stm32f4xx.h`

    - `stm32f407xx.h`

The latter two are automatic - as long as `-DSTM32F407xx` is passed in your pre-processor flags.

Comment: Sorry, it was worth mentioning. The -DSTM32F407xx Flag is set. (otherwise I would have also got the error: "Please select first the target STM32F4xx device used in your application (in stm32f4xx.h file)"). Any other ideas?

Comment: @Drimer: Can you post the relevant parts of your Makefile?

Comment: I modified my questions and would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

`core_cm4.h` is not supposed to be included directly.

Instead, you `#define` the MCU *line*, and `#include` the header for the MCU *series*.

```
#define STM32F407xx
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
```

That would include `stm32f407xx.h` which in turn includes `core_cm4.h`.

Including `stm32f407xx.h` directly, without the `#define` might work too.

Comment: Hey. Thank you for your answer. I added these lines but I still have problems there. I modified my question. Can you look into it again?

Answer (score 0):

`IRQn_Type` is basically a enumeration that holds the value of all types of interrupts the controller have. For example

```
enum    IRQn_Type { 
  NonMaskableInt_IRQn = -14, 
  HardFault_IRQn = -13, 
  MemoryManagement_IRQn = -12, 
  BusFault_IRQn = -11, 
  UsageFault_IRQn = -10, 
  SecureFault_IRQn = -9, 
  SVCall_IRQn = -5, 
  DebugMonitor_IRQn = -4, 
  PendSV_IRQn = -2, 
  SysTick_IRQn = -1, 
  WWDG_STM_IRQn = 0, 
  PVD_STM_IRQn = 1 
}
```

If it is not present your header file that means file is corrupted or someone had made changes is that file. Replace your file with new one might solve your problem.