# Using CMSIS with baremetal ARM cortex-M0 on Texas Instruments

Tags: embedded, bare-metal, hal, texas-instruments, cmsis

I'm trying to integrate CMSIS-Core into a project that uses the [MSPMOL-1306-Q1](https://www.ti.com/product/MSPM0L1305-Q1) MCU from Texas Instruments. Most examples seem to be for STM32 Cube MCUs. For instance, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56489064/unknown-datatypes-irqn-type) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71626597/what-are-the-various-ways-to-disable-and-re-enable-interrupts-in-stm32-microcont).

I am facing an error that the OP from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56489064/unknown-datatypes-irqn-type) question is facing. However to my dismay, the answer is for STM32.

As per [this](https://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless-connectivity/sub-1-ghz-group/sub-1-ghz/f/sub-1-ghz-forum/770684/ccs-cc1352p-using-cmsis-with-code-composer-studio-8-3-00009/2854682), CMSIS only seems to be supported for MSP432. But that was over 5 years ago.

So has anyone here been able to successfully integrate CMSIS with CortexM0 MCUs from TI?

Comment: Don't make us have to follow multiple links to understand your question.  Include the error information in your question.

Comment: Why doesn't TI offer this or point you in the right direction to a tool chain which does? Don't pick parts with non-existent support.

Comment: All your links relate to Cortex-M4 so possibly _not_ the same error at all. Ensure your question is standalone coherent and accurate by including your _own_ information.

Comment: Your link to the MSP432 question does not imply that M0 is not supported.  It is about FPU support on M4 and entirely irrelevant to your issue.

Comment: @Clifford there ARE no questions that I could find about using CMSIS bare-metal with Cortex-M0plus which is why i linked to the ones that were the closest to what I wanted.

Comment: @AjB  you have missed the point.  Even if you think those links are supporting information, you need to provide information on the error you are seeing in your build in this question, not link to a different question for a different processor and a different toolchain and say it is the _same_.  A problem can have the same or superficially similar symptoms but a different cause. The M0 CMSIS core is _different_ from that of the M3 and M4.

Comment: ... moreover the part is M0+ not M0 - not the same thing at all.  Perhaps that is your problem if you are trying to use M0 CMSIS with M0+?

Comment: The first link is to 1305 not 1306?

Comment: As well as downloading from ARM, the CMSIS is included in the [MSPM0-SDK](https://www.ti.com/tool/MSPM0-SDK) already integrated.  Are you using that? You probably should.

Comment: @Lundin ... or in this case don't ignore the support clearly provided.

Answer (score 0):

CMSIS-Core supports Cortex-M0 as described at https://arm-software.github.io/CMSIS_5/Core/html/index.html.

The current source can be obtained from https://www.arm.com/technologies/cmsis.  It is delivered as source code; to use it with a project you can simply include it in your project in the normal manner.

However you would be wise to use the provided [TI SDK](https://www.ti.com/tool/MSPM0-SDK) which includes the CMSIS and a whole bunch of part specific support *already "integrated"* with documentation and examples for IAR, Keil and TI CCS:

The IDE or target should make no difference unless you have tied itself into a particular vendor's package management, which is often best avoided as it makes it difficult to migrate code between projects using different vendor MCUs, and may mean you get updates that you might not want or need, or would rather apply at a time of your choosing.